# Error en php 7.3.10

Tags: php, php7

despues de cambiar a un host que tiene php 7+ me salta un error y entiendo que es por ser una version nueva que obliga cambiar el codigo php .

Pero no tengo idea de alternativa.

> Warning: Use of undefined constant nombre - assumed 'nombre' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   /home/cristal/public_html/webmin/image-proyectos.php on line 258

La linia 258:

```
<th><a href="upload-image-proyectos-fotos.php?id='.ucwords(str_replace(" ","-",$row[nombre])).'&id2=' . $row["id"]. '"><img class="img-fluid float-right ml-5 mb-4 mt-4" src="https://www.cristaleriaiberica.es/' . $row["img"]. '" alt="Cristaleria Iberica" height="63" width="80"/></a></th>
```

Pienso que la problema es

> .ucwords(str_replace(" ","-",$row[nombre])).

Como lo puedo solucionar? gracias

Comment: Hola mira el codigo que colas es puro html o esta dentro de php si esta en html puro te faltan las etiquetas de php.

Comment: e puesto solo la linia 258 que es dentro de echo"";

Comment: Pues te falta encerrar `nombre` entre comillas no? por que así como esta pareciera una constante

Comment: Aprendiz tienes razón esto era el fallo. gracias.